# TicTacToe - generating solutions

Tags: java, math, tic-tac-toe

Given a grid of nxn squares, where each square has an id, the first(top left) square has id 0 (so a 5x5 grid will have ids 0-24) like below:

```
00 01 02 03 04

05 06 07 08 09

10 11 12 13 14

15 16 17 18 19

20 21 22 23 24
```

I need to generate all diagonal solutions of length Y. So if Y is 3, then some of the solutions will be:

```
0,6,12
```

and

```
11,17,23
```

but obviously NOT

```
3,9,15 (because the 15 does not follow on diagonally)
```

Any ideas how these solutions can be generated?

This is what I've got so far (dimension = 5, inARow = 3):

```
public ArrayList<int[]> getSolutions(int dimension, int inARow) {

    ArrayList<int[]> solutions = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    //create row solutions
    for(int i=0; i<dimension*dimension; i = i+dimension) {
        for(int j=i; j<=i+dimension - inARow; j++){            
            int[] row = new int[inARow];
            int counter = 0;
            for(int k=j; k<j+inARow; k++){
                row[counter++] = k;
            }
            solutions.add(row);
        }
    }

    //create column solutions        
    for(int i=0;i<dimension;i++){
        for(int j=i; j<(dimension*dimension)-(dimension*inARow)+dimension;j=j+dimension){
            int[] col = new int[inARow];
            int counter = 0;
            for(int k=j;k<j+(dimension*inARow);k=k+dimension){
                col[counter++] = k;
            }
            solutions.add(col);
        }
    }

    //create diagonals        
    for(int i=0; i<dimension*dimension; i++){            
        for(int j=i; j<i+(dimension * inARow); j = j+dimension+1){
            System.out.println(j);
        }            
    }                

    return solutions;
```

This gives me all the diagonal solutions but also gives me the bad ones like 3,9,15. Im having trouble eliminating those.

Anti-diagonals are also solutions so 2,6,10 would also be a solution but if I get normal diagonals working I can probably do the same for anti-diagonals.

Comment: What are some of your ideas or things you've tried?

Comment: This probably is an easy one for us, however what code / algorithm have you written?

Comment: Is 2, 6, 10 a valid solution?

Comment: Please read the [faq] and [ask] for guidelines on how to post on SO.

Comment: In the above code 'dimension' refers to row/column length so on a 5X5 board 'dimension' would be 5. 'inARow' is how many squares make up a solution so this could be 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your lucky day... I updated the answer to work as a general solution for all grid sizes and lengths

In coffee script, which makes nice pseudo code

```
w = 5 # width of the grid
h = 5 # height of the grid
l = 3 # length to capture

m = [] # matches

for i in [0..(w*h)-1] # loop through each square
    col = i % w # calculate what column we are in
    row = Math.floor i / w # calculate what row we are in
    nums = [] # re-set matched lines array
    if col < w - (l-1) and row < h - (l-1) # if there is space for diagonal right
        for j in [0..l-1] # loop until length is reached
            nums.push i+(j*w)+j # push it onto the array of squares
        m.push nums # push into the array of matched lines
    nums = []
    if col > l-2 and row < h-l+1 # if there is space for diagonal left
        for j in [0..l-1]
            nums.push i+(j*w)-j
        m.push nums

console.dir m
# or
console.log i.join "," for i in m
```

Which compiles to javascript (so you can test it)

```
var col, h, i, j, l, m, nums, row, w, _i, _len, _ref, _ref2, _ref3;
w = 5;
h = 5;
l = 3;
m = [];
for (i = 0, _ref = (w * h) - 1; 0 <= _ref ? i <= _ref : i >= _ref; 0 <= _ref ? i++ : i--) {
  col = i % w;
  row = Math.floor(i / w);
  nums = [];
  if (col < w - (l - 1) && row < h - (l - 1)) {
    for (j = 0, _ref2 = l - 1; 0 <= _ref2 ? j <= _ref2 : j >= _ref2; 0 <= _ref2 ? j++ : j--) {
      nums.push(i + (j * w) + j);
    }
    m.push(nums);
  }
  nums = [];
  if (col > l - 2 && row < h - l + 1) {
    for (j = 0, _ref3 = l - 1; 0 <= _ref3 ? j <= _ref3 : j >= _ref3; 0 <= _ref3 ? j++ : j--) {
      nums.push(i + (j * w) - j);
    }
    m.push(nums);
  }
}
console.dir(m);
for (_i = 0, _len = m.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  i = m[_i];
  console.log(i.join(","));
}
```

Comment: Hi, the problem with that code is that it assumes a solution requires 3 squares. This will be dynamically decided along with board size but could be any number.

Comment: @King_Kratos So figure it out from there. Don't expect an entire answer for exactly what you need just because you asked for it.

Comment: This answer has me convinced I should learn coffeescript.  Can you recommend a tutorial?

Comment: the [coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/) site has lots of great examples of the syntax, and online test area. Here is a great one liner to appreciate the conciseness `console.log ['fizz' unless i%3] + ['buzz' unless i%5] or i for i in [1..100]
`. But the best thing about coffee-script is the way it re-writes your code into [better patterns](http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/04_idioms.html) - to fix some of javascript's shortcomings.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Billy Moon. I converted your Javascript to Java and indeed it works. I Have tried to go through the your code and understand it but it is quite difficult with so many variables. Since I spent a long time trying to figure the solution myself, I would be very grateful if you could briefly tell me how yours works or on what maths principles. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry I only read the javascript, didnt realise your coffeescript has comments. Thanks

Comment: Yeah - coffee script compiles into javascript, and strips the comments. Coffee Script reads almost like pseudo code, and the produced javascript, although not very human friendly, does run well. You should post the Java version in case someone else in your class needs it ;)